# Invalid anonymous type member declarator using data-url html attribute

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a small project using jQuery, MVC4 with Razon and C#. In my view I have a drop down list and I wish to give it the attribute  of `data-url=Url.Action("UpdateDeliveryAddress", "Home")`:

```
<div class="@dropDownListClass">
    @Html.DropDownList("theList", null, new {data-url=Url.Action("UpdateDeliveryAddress", "Home") })
</div>
```

However, when I do so, I get the follow error:

```
invalid anonymous type member declarator anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignemnt, simple name or member access.
```

What am I missing? Why do I have this error?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`data-url` is not a valid C# identifier.

Instead, use `data_url`.
MVC will replace `_` with `-`.