# @Html.RadioButtonFor: Invalid anonymous type member declarator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to show a popup on radio button selection.

I use MVC razor.

Following is my code

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Container.Type, Model.container.type.1,
                       new { id = "type1", @class = "validate[required]", data-toggle = "modal", data-target = "#Modal" })
```

I get following error

**CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member acce**

Seems that the attributes data-toggle and data-target dont work with @Html.RadioButtonFor()

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Container.Type, ...` (lower case `m`) but what is `Model.container.type.1`? And it needs to be `data_toggle` (underscrore when used on anonymous objects)

Comment: The proper attribute usage in HTML helper is `data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#Modal"`. And why it bound to `Model.Container.Type` while the expression contains `m` binder (it should be `m => m.Container.Type` or something like that)?

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920431/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator-using-data-url-html-attribute & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196776/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator-anonymous-type-members-must-be-declare.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Container.Type, Model.container.type.1, new { id = "type1", @class = "validate[required]", dataToggle = "modal", dataTarget = "#Modal" })
```

Hyphen sign can't be used in a variable name. You can use camel-case notation instead

If you have no choice but to use hyphen, use underscore. It will be automatically replace by hyphen.

Comment: Its no longer a `data-` attribute using `dataToggle = "modal"` (just an invalid attribute) and  camel-case is pointless since it will be converted to lower case